# Multi-task learning with sample weights in tensorflow -- shape problem

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm doing sequence classification, I've got batch sizes of 1, 5 outcomes, and variable time steps (14 in this example).  My sample weights `w` are the same shape as my label `y`:

```
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones(shape = (1,14,5)))
w = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.uniform(size = (1,14,5)))

y.shape
Out[53]: TensorShape([1, 14, 5])

w.shape
Out[54]: TensorShape([1, 14, 5])
```

When I try to run this through the loss function, I get the following error:

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
loss_object(y_true = y, 
            y_pred = y,
            sample_weight = w)

InvalidArgumentError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 5 [Op:Squeeze]
```

what's going on?  It should be a straightforward multiplication of a loss matrix (pre-reduction) with the weights.  How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super simple fix! Tensorflow squeezes the last dimension of the sample weights because they are supposed to be applied per sample, therefore, all you need to do is add one dimension to your weight matrix along the last axis:

```
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.ones(shape = (1,14,5)))
w = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.random.uniform(size = (1,14,5,1))) # Change made here
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
loss_object(y_true = y, 
            y_pred = y,
            sample_weight = w)
```

You can also just change the shape of the weights matrix after creation:

```
w = tf.expand_dims(w, axis=-1)
```